# Creating new array from unique elements found in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique, element

I was given an assignment:

> Finding unique elements in an array and creating a new array from these unique elements.

[The professor gave us the pseudocode to code this assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L72Ge.png) - it should be straightforward but my code is not working.

Here is my attempt:

```js
// search for unique birthdays in the array
function find(birthdays) {
  var uniqueBirthdays = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= birthdays.length; i = i + 2) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var j = 1; j <= birthdays.length; j = j + 2) {
      if (birthdays[i] == birthdays[j]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count == 1) {
      var n = uniqueBirthdays.length;
      uniqueBirthdays[n] = birthdays[i - 1];
    }
  }
  return uniqueBirthdays;
}
```

I have tried checking for indentation errors as well as a number of other things but can not figure out why as the array is traversed it is giving each element a count of only 1 (meaning there are no matching elements) - it does not seem to be traversing the array more than once so no elements have a count greater than 1 - even though I am using nested for loops.

I have increased the intervals by 2 because I need to compare every other element - there is a number assigned to each birthday so the array may look like:

```
['0001'][12/15]['0002'[03/12]...
```

I am brand new so I may be overlooking simple but ive tried so many things and i can not understand why this code isnt working - it is returning back all of the elements that are assigned to the birthdays instead of just the unique ones.

Any help that will point me in the right direction is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, and there were just a couple mistakes. The only things that did not work were the way you wrote your `for` loops:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= birthdays.length; i = i + 2) {
```

- Array indexes start at `0`, so if you want to process the first element, use `var i = 0;`
- Since these indexes start at `0`, for an Array of `3` elements, the last index is `2`. So you only want to run your loop while `i` is **less** than the array length: `i < birthdays.length`
- You were skipping elements by doing `i = i + 2`. There seems to be no reason for it?

Something else worth mentionning: in JS, indentation does not matter - well, it does, but only to avoid making your eyes bleed. In fact, most websites use minified versions of their code, which fits on a single *(often very long and ugly)* line ([example](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js)).

Here is your code, with only two lines fixed:

```js
function find(birthdays) {
  var uniqueBirthdays = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < birthdays.length; i = i + 1) { // <-----
    var count = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < birthdays.length; j = j + 1) { // <-----
      if (birthdays[i] == birthdays[j]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count == 1) {
      var n = uniqueBirthdays.length;
      uniqueBirthdays[n] = birthdays[i];
    }
  }
  return uniqueBirthdays;
}
// I used letters instead of birthdays for easier demo checking
var birthdays = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'];
console.log( find(birthdays) ); // ["b", "c"]
```

Comment: Blex- thank you very much! So the first half of the class was focused on pseudocode and we are now implementing it in js- I took a class in Python previously and didn’t realize indentation didn’t matter in js- appreciate the info. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

JS have direct methods tor that use [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), [Array.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) and [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

uniques elements have same  first position and last position

sample code:

```js
const initailArray = [...'ldfkjlqklnmbnmykdshgmkudqjshmjfhmsdjhmjh']

const uniqueLetters = initailArray.filter((c,i,a)=>a.indexOf(c)===a.lastIndexOf(c)).sort()

 
console.log(JSON.stringify(uniqueLetters))
```